# Persist a RelationshipEntity that is not a NodeEntity property

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

In SDN4 I wish to persist a `@RelationshipEntity` which is not a `@NodeEntity`'s property. 
Example:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User{
    Long id;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type="FOLLOWS")
public class Follows{
    @GraphId   private Long relationshipId;
    @StartNode private User follower;
    @EndNode   private User followee;
    @Property  private Date from;

    public Follows(){}
    public Follows(User u1, User u2){
         this.follower = u1;
         this.followee = u2;
    }
}

@Repository
interface FollowsRepository extends GraphRepository<Follows>{}
```

And then persist the `Follows` @Relationship like this

```
...
followsRepository.save(new Follows(user1, user2));
...
```

But when doing so, the Relationship is not persisted!!

**Sadly** as stated in the accepted answer this cannot (yet) be done (SDN 4.0.0.RELEASE)

### Workaround 1

It is possible to persist `@RelationshipEntities` using `@Query` in `GraphRepositories`.

```
@Query("Match (a:User), (b:User) WHERE id(a) = {0} 
                     AND id(b) = {1} CREATE (a)-[r:FOLLOWS {date:{2}}]->(b) RETURN r ")
```

### Workaround 2

This can also be done by treating `Follows` as a `@NodeEntity`, which might not be the most performant thing to do **BUT** will not affect any of the `@NodeEntities` of the domain, nor the service layer **AND** you won't have to mess with the depth factor when loading and persisting entities

```
@NodeEntity
public class User{
    Long id;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Follows{
    private Long Id;
    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWER")
    private User follower;
    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWEE")
    private User followee;
    private Date from;

    public Follows(){}
    public Follows(User u1, User u2){
         this.follower = u1;
         this.followee = u2;
    }
}

....
//Placed in userService
Follows createFollowsRelationship(User u1, User u2){
   return followsRepository.save(new Follows(user1, user2));
}
.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you cannot persist a relationship entity directly when it is not referenced from participating node entities.
You'll have to save the start node and make sure it has a reference to the relationship entity.

There will be some enhancements around how relationship entities are persisted but not in the next release.

Comment: "There will be some enhancements..." Do you mean this will be fixed?

Comment: @Xipo Do you mean that your question concerns a bug, rather than a feature request?

Comment: Well I think of it as a bug because of 1. The above used to be supported, and now is not 2. No Exceptions or Errors are thrown when trying to persist a relationship in such a way (it just doesn't work) 3. The reference (and specifically migration) guide makes no reference to what should be expected. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Xipo it works as designed in SDN 4. SDN 4 expects that your object model be consistent with the graph model. Agree that this has not been documented well, and docs have been updated already for the next release. In the meanwhile, http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/09/03/sdn-4-object-model.html talks more about the object model

Comment: @Luanne I have edited the question so that it does not imply that it refers to a bug. Since though `Relationships` are `Entities` of the domain, shouldn't they be able to be persisted just like any other `Entity`? Also, could we have some insight whether this feature will be supported in the future? Thank you!!! :D

Comment: @Xipo yes, will be supported in the future. Relationship entities are currently persisted by navigating to the start node and persisting it. That's why it does not work when the start node does not have a reference to the relationship entity.

Comment: @Luanne Thank you, thats great!! I understood how it works but did not want to change my domain model.